# How to manage shared object lifetimes with static casts?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, static-cast

I am new to C++ style casts, and need help in understanding how the code below works (this is some dummy code I wrote to understand things).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class A { 
public:
    A() : a(1) {
        std::cout << "Creating A\n";
    }   
    ~A() {
        std::cout << "Destroying A\n";
    }   
    int a;
};

class B : public A { 
public:
    B() : b(2) {
        std::cout << "Creating B\n";
    }   
    ~B() {
        std::cout << "Destroying B\n";
    }   
    int b;
};

int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<B> objectB(new B());
    {   
    std::shared_ptr<A> (static_cast<A*>(objectB.get()));
    std::cout << "End of inner scope\n";
    }   
    std::cout << "End of outer scope\n";
}
```

It prints

```
Creating A
Creating B
Destroying A
End of inner scope
End of outer scope
Destroying B
Destroying A
```

My understanding:

```
Creating A         -> B's ctor calls base class ctor
Creating B         -> B's ctor
Destroying A       -> ???
End of inner scope
End of outer scope
Destroying B       -> B's dtor
Destroying A       -> B's dtor calls base dtor
```

Why do I get the first `Destroying A` and what exactly is happening here?! How can A be destroyed twice?

Comment: This is not a full answer, but you have two independent shared pointers pointing to the same thing. So at some point there will be more than one attempt to free the managed object, which is undefined behaviour. Also, try to flush the stdout buffer by using `std::endl` instead of just `\n`.

Comment: I think your point about undefined behavior makes sense, although I am still trying to find a reference to this. I know `endl` might help in flushing, but it doesn't change the order.

Comment: @Lazer: it *is* UB to delete the same object more than once (maybe searching for *double-delete* will be easier to find?), which is what happens in your code. Also, you should use a virtual destructor in the base class to ensure derived objects get properly cleaned up when deleted through a base class pointer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you make sure the output is flushed (by using `std::endl`, for example), you get

> Creating A
>
> Creating B
>
> Destroying A
>
> End of inner scope
>
> End of outer scope
>
> Destroying B
>
> Destroying A

the reason for the double delete of `A` is that you are constructing a `shared_ptr` from a raw pointer here:

```
std::shared_ptr<A> (static_cast<A*>(objectB.get()));
```

This `shared_ptr` is completely independent of the first one, and has its own reference count. So when the scope ends, it attempts to delete the `A` pointer it holds. If you had done this instead:

```
std::shared_ptr<A>{objectB};
```

then you wouldn't have encountered the problem. Note there is no need for a `static_cast` here.

Note that `A` should have a `virtual` destructor. `shared_ptr` has a clever destruction mechanism which means that this is not crucial in this example, but in general, if you are going to delete objects polymorphically, the base class must have a virtual destructor.

Comment: Also, because you don't have virtual destructors on `A` or `B`, the wrong type of destructor gets called.

Comment: @JoeZ Right, although `shared_ptr` is a bit special about this. I added a note about it.

Comment: What does the `{}` syntax mean? Does it call the constructor in some special way?

Comment: @Lazer No, in this case it just calls the constructor. There is nothing special about it, except that it can never be parsed as a function declaration, unlike the `()` equivalents. Look up "C++11 uniform initialization".

Comment: Thanks, one last thing, if I don't need `objectB`, is it safe to do `std::shared_ptr<A> objectA(new B());`?

Comment: @Lazer yes, it is safe. But give `A` a virtual destructor.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case it wasn't clear from juanchopanza's answer, this line

```
std::shared_ptr<A> (static_cast<A*>(objectB.get()));
```

is incorrect and leads to undefined behavior.

The shared pointer you construct here just takes the pointer you give it. It has no idea that the object pointed to by that pointer is already owned by another smart pointer. Furthermore it doesn't know that the pointer points to a sub-object and that the pointer will need to be cast back to `B*` in order to be `delete`d, because the `static_cast` hides that information from it.

To cast smart pointers you need a cast that understands and is integrated with smart pointers. C++ has **`std::static_pointer_cast`** and **`std::dynamic_pointer_cast`** for this purpose.

```
int main() {
  std::shared_ptr<B> objectB(new B());
  {   
    std::shared_ptr<A> x = std::static_pointer_cast<A>(objectB);
    std::cout << "End of inner scope\n";
  }   
  std::cout << "End of outer scope\n";
}
```

With this code the output of your program shows correct behavior:

```
make A
make B
End of inner scope
End of outer scope
~B
~A
```

Of course in this particular case you don't need an explicit cast, because `std::shared_ptr` can figure out legal up-casts and do them implicitly. You need `std::static_pointer_cast` to do down-casts though:

```
int main() {
  std::shared_ptr<A> objectA(new B());
  {   
    std::shared_ptr<B> x = std::static_pointer_cast<B>(objectA);
    std::cout << "End of inner scope\n";
  }   
  std::cout << "End of outer scope\n";
}
```

> Thanks, one last thing, if I don't need objectB, is it safe to do `std::shared_ptr<A> objectA(new B());`?

Yes, this does happen to be safe. The `shared_ptr<A>` constructor receives a `B*` and knows enough to store the fact that when deletion occurs it will need to convert the `A*` that it holds to `B*`. This ensures that the object gets deleted correctly.

However, if you really want your types `A` and `B` to behave polymorphically then you should probably just make them polymorphic types by adding virtual destructors, and then you don't have to worry about how smart `std::shared_ptr` is about this.